# Language Block customization: I need to display either English link or the other language link (not both)

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a bilingual project and the language is being switched from the language block. It actually displays now: English and Spanish.

I need to have just one language link displayed: English when on Spanish language and Spanish when English.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the current language link gets an "active" class. You can use CSS to hide all other links and display only the active link.

This can also be done by overriding theme template files or functions.

Comment: in jQuery something like $(language-switcher-locale-url:not(active)).hide();. I think that's it.